# Subset of string variable in Makefile

Tags: make

I am relatively new to using Make. I am trying to port a shell script that has a variable that is accessed using `${var:9:-1}`, however in Make as `$` is reserved I cannot use this convention. I am lost as whenever I try to search for answers they are extremely verbose.

eg:

```
foo:
        bar=`abc|xyz`
        baz -n ${bar:9:-1}
```

Comment: just double the `$`. `baz -n $${bar:9:-1}`. But each line is executed in a different shell, so you should put them on the same line: ```bar=`abc|xyz`; baz -n $${bar:9:-1}```, otherwise the `bar` variable will be empty.

Comment: Note that the shell command from a Makefile will by defnition be executed in a typically POSIX compliant shell and that does not support the expression `${bar:9:-1}` because this uses a `ksh/bash` extension.